# How do I wait for Sproutcore 2.0 to have loaded all templates?

Tags: javascript, sproutcore, sproutcore-2

In my app, the `<body>` tag contains just a single `<script type="text/x-handlebars>` tag which contains all my views. Sproutcore 2.0 nicely adds a jQuery on-document-ready handler that parses those templates and renders them back into the DOM.

I'd like to call a function on one of the views as soon as it's rendered. The problem is that the re-insertion happens asynchronously, so I don't know when the view is available.

#### Example

Page

```
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    ...
    {{view "MyApp.TweetInputView"}}
    ...
  </script>
</body>
```

View:

```
MyApp.TweetInputView = SC.View.extend({
  init: function() {
    // act like a singleton
    MyApp.TweetInputView.instance = this;
    return this._super();
  },
  focus: function() {
    ...
    this.$().focus();
  }
});
```

Initializer

```
// if the URL is /tweets/new, focus on the tweet input view
$(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/tweets/new') {
    // doesn't work, because the view hasn't been created yet:
    MyApp.TweetInputView.instance.focus();
  }
});
```

I've also tried `SC.run.schedule('render', function() { MyApp.TweetInputView.instance.focus(); }, 'call');` in the hopes that Sproutcore would run that after all the view rendering and insertion, but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyApp.TweetInputView = SC.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log("I've been rendered!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. That seems like it will work, but it means that the logic I have in my initializer ("if I'm in the right section of the app") now also exists in my view. I really want to keep control of that focus call in the routing code.

Comment: This does, however suggest a solution that is very good: create a view class for the wrapper for my page (`MyApp.RootView`) with a `didInsertElement` function that starts the routing framework running!